# Motor control PLC in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, multithreading, device-driver

#### Project description

We have different types of devices like *sov*, *motor*, *analog*, *digital*, *control valves* etc. Each type of device has 100 items.

Now our software continuously monitors with the PLC to read some property of each type according to which we need to write some property.

As an example, if motor on command is high then we need to write on feedback at PLC end high. At the moment, I face the problem that it takes too much time to update.

Now I describe my software architecture:

1. I make individual class for each types of device. As an example for motor:

   ```
   class Fn_Motor1D:



       def __init__(self,com,df,idxNo):

           self._idxNo =idxNo
           self.gen = com
           self.df = df
           self.setup()
           self.initilizedigitalinput()


       def setup(self):
           try:

               for tag,col in self.readalltags():

                   if col==3:
                       self.cmd = str(tag)


                   if col == 4:
                       self.runingFB = str(tag)


                   if col == 5:
                       self.remoteFB = str(tag)


                   if col == 6:
                       self.healthyFB = str(tag)


                   if col == 7:
                       self.readyFB = str(tag)


                   if col == 8:
                       self.mccbonFeedBack = str(tag)

                   if col == 9:
                       self.overloadFeedBack = str(tag)


                   if col == 10:
                       self.faultFB =str(tag)


                   if col == 11:
                       self.delaytime = tag



           except Exception as e:
               print("exception raise",e.args)
               log_exception(e)

       def initilizedigitalinput(self):
           try:
               if len(self.healthyFB) > 3:
                   self.gen.writegeneral.writenodevalue(self.healthyFB, 1)
               else:
                   pass

               if len(self.remoteFB) > 3:
                   self.gen.writegeneral.writenodevalue(self.remoteFB, 1)
               else:
                   pass

               if len(self.readyFB) > 3:
                   self.gen.writegeneral.writenodevalue(self.readyFB, 1)
               else:
                   pass

               if len(self.mccbonFeedBack) > 3:
                   self.gen.writegeneral.writenodevalue(self.mccbonFeedBack, 1)
               else:
                   pass

               if len(self.overloadFeedBack) > 3:
                   self.gen.writegeneral.writenodevalue(self.overloadFeedBack, 0)
               else:
                   pass

               if len(self.faultFB) > 3:
                   self.gen.writegeneral.writenodevalue(self.faultFB, 0)
               else:
                   pass
           except Exception as e :
               log_exception(e)


       def process(self):

           try:

               oncommandvalue = self.gen.readgeneral.readtagvalue(self.cmd)
               if oncommandvalue:
                   sleep(self.delaytime)
                   self.gen.writegeneral.writenodevalue(self.runingFB, 1)
               else:
                   self.gen.writegeneral.writenodevalue(self.runingFB, 0)

           except Exception as e:
               log_exception(e)



       def readalltags(self):
           n = 3
           row, col = self.df.shape
           print(col)
           while n < col:
               data = self.df.iloc[self._idxNo, n]
               yield data,n
               n = n + 1
   ```
2. Call all motor devices at one class and make `listofallmotor1d` devices.

   ```
   class Cal_AllMotor1D:

       def __init__(self,df,com):
           self.df = df
           self.com = com
           self.listofmotor1D = []
           self.setup()


       def setup(self):
           try:
               n =0
               self.listofmotor1D.clear()
               while n< len(self.df.index):
                   self.df.iloc[n, 0] = Fn_Motor1D(self.com, self.df, n)
                   self.listofmotor1D.append(self.df.iloc[n,0])
                   n = n + 1


           except Exception as e :
               print(e.args)
               log_exception(e)

       def process(self):
           n = 0
           while n < len(self.listofmotor1Dir):
               self.listofmotor1Dir[n].process()
               n = n + 1




       @property
       def listofmotor1Dir(self):
           if len(self.listofmotor1D) > 0:
               return self.listofmotor1D
   ```
3. Now I make `AllDevices` class where I call the all device and write monitoring process:

   ```
   import callallmotor1D
   import callallmotor2D_V1
   import callallsov1S_V1
   import callallsov2S_V1
   import calallanalog_V1
   import calallcontrolvalves_V1
   import callallvibrofeeder_V1
   import callallconveyor_V1

   import pandas as pd

   class AllDevices:

       def __init__(self,comobject):


           self._comobject = comobject
           dfM1D = pd.read_excel(r'D:\OPCUA\Working_VF1.xls', sheet_name='Motor1D')
           dfM2D = pd.read_excel(r'D:\OPCUA\Working_VF1.xls', sheet_name='Motor2D')
           dfsov1S = pd.read_excel(r'D:\OPCUA\Working_VF1.xls', sheet_name='Valve1S')
           dfsov2S = pd.read_excel(r'D:\OPCUA\Working_VF1.xls', sheet_name='Valve2S')
           dfanalog = pd.read_excel(r'D:\OPCUA\Working_VF1.xls', sheet_name='AnalogTx')
           dfcontrolvalve = pd.read_excel(r'D:\OPCUA\Working_VF1.xls', sheet_name='ControlValves')
           dfvibrofeeder = pd.read_excel(r'D:\OPCUA\Working_VF1.xls', sheet_name='VibroFeeder')
           dfconveyor = pd.read_excel(r'D:\OPCUA\Working_VF1.xls', sheet_name='Conveyor')


           self.allmotor1dobjects = callallmotor1D.Cal_AllMotor1D(dfM1D, comobject)
           self.allmotor2dobjects =  callallmotor2D_V1.Cal_AllMotor2D(dfM2D,comobject)
           self.allsov1sobjects = callallsov1S_V1.Cal_AllSov1S(dfsov1S,comobject)
           self.allsov2sobjects = callallsov2S_V1.Cal_AllSov2S(dfsov2S, comobject)
           self.allanalogobjects = calallanalog_V1.Cal_AllAnalogInputs(dfanalog,comobject)
           self.allcontrolvalveobjects = calallcontrolvalves_V1.Cal_AllControlValve(dfcontrolvalve,comobject)
           self.allvibrofeederobjects = callallvibrofeeder_V1.Cal_AllVibroFeeder(dfvibrofeeder,comobject)
           self.allconveyorobjects = callallconveyor_V1.Cal_AllConveyor1D(dfconveyor,comobject)



       def allmotor1dprocessing(self):
           self.allmotor1dobjects.process()
           self.allmotor1dobjects.process()

       def allmotor2dprocessing(self):
           self.allmotor2dobjects.process()

       def allsov1sprocessing(self):
           self.allsov1sobjects.process()

       def allanalogsprocessing(self):
           self.allanalogobjects.process()

       def allcontrolvaleprocessing(self):
           self.allcontrolvalveobjects.process()

       def allvibrofeederprocessing(self):
           self.allvibrofeederobjects.process()

       def allconveyorprocessing(self):
           self.allconveyorobjects.process()
   ```
4. At the end I all devices class in my main UI and run seperate thread each device type:-

   ```
               def allmotor1dprocess():
                       while True :
                               self.callalldevices.allmotor1dprocessing()

               def allmotor2dprocess():
                       while True:
                               self.callalldevices.allmotor2dprocessing()



               def allsov1sprocess():
                       while True:
                               self.callalldevices.allsov1sprocessing()



               def allananlogprocess():
                       while True:
                               self.callalldevices.allanalogsprocessing()

               def allcontrolvalveprocess():
                       while True:
                               self.callalldevices.allcontrolvaleprocessing()

               def allconveyorprocess():
                       while True:
                               self.callalldevices.allconveyorprocessing()


              self.writeallmotor1dthread = threading.Thread(target=allmotor1dprocess)
           self.writeallmotor2dthread =threading.Thread(target=allmotor2dprocess)
           self.writeallsov1sthread1 = threading.Thread(target=allsov1sprocess)
           self.writeallsov1sthread2 = threading.Thread(target=allsov1sprocess2)
           self.writeallsov2sthread = threading.Thread(target=allsov2sprocess)
           self.writeallanalogthread = threading.Thread(target=allananlogprocess)
           self.writeallcontrolvalvethread = threading.Thread(target=allcontrolvalveprocess)
           self.writeallconveyorthread = threading.Thread(target=allconveyorprocess)

           self.writeallmotor1dthread.start()
           self.writeallmotor2dthread.start()
           self.writeallsov1sthread1.start()
           self.writeallsov1sthread2.start()
           self.writeallsov2sthread.start()
           self.writeallanalogthread.start()
           self.writeallcontrolvalvethread.start()
           self.writeallconveyorthread.start()
   ```

In this software architecture I really face problem to update the plc data.

As an example, let's suppose that I give on command for a motor. This will take time to update its run feedback. So, I need your expert view on this.
Please let me know how I can improve my coding to get process faster.

Comment: Hello all any help?

Comment: You are on Code Review here. It's not unusual that answers take at least few hours to several days, depending on the amount of code and the depth of the review.

Comment: It is okye  Alex ..Please take your time.Actually my current project is put on hold. I need your help.If you are able to give me some feedback after this weekend, it would be good.please reply if you are interested to review my code.If you need any further information I can help you.Thank you